# KeyError in Discord.py musicbot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I get a `KeyError` that says my discord ip every time I try this

```
players = {}

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@is_vale()
async def pause(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.server.id
    players[id].pause()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description='Musik wurde pausiert.', 
        color=botcolor
    )
    await client.say(embed=embed)
```

The Error looks like this

```
 File "C:\Users\asche\Desktop\discord bot\bot\musikbot (1).py", line 98, in pause
    players[id].pause()
KeyError: '510767063510417418'
```

Comment: You never add any players to that dictionary in your code, either the snippet is incomplete (in which case please update it) or that is your actual error

Comment: already fixed it but thx anyways

Comment: Then please update the question with the correct snippet and add an answer explaining how it was solved. This is helpful for other people encountering similar issues and allows them to solve it without asking first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it and changed the code by doing so. so here is the new code

```
    def check_queue(id):
        if queues[id] != []:
            player = queues[id].pop(0)
            players[id] = player
            player.start()
        else:
            del players[id]

    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(ctx, url):
        server = ctx.message.server
        voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
        try:
            if players[server.id].is_playing():
                player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url,ytdl_options=ytdl_format_options, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))

                if server.id in queues:
                    queues[server.id].append(player)
                else:
                    queues[server.id] = [player]
                embed = discord.Embed(description='{} ist in der Playlist.'.format(url), color=botcolor)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
            else:
                player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, ytdl_options=ytdl_format_options, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))
                embed = discord.Embed(description='{} wird abgespielt.'.format(url), color=botcolor)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                await songs.put(player)
                players[server.id] = player
                player.start()
        except KeyError:
                player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, ytdl_options=ytdl_format_options, after=lambda: check_queue(server.id))
                embed = discord.Embed(description='{} wird abgespielt.'.format(url), color=botcolor)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                await songs.put(player)
                players[server.id] = player
                player.start()
```